# google chrome window resizes when click 12.04 kde

Tags: 12.04, kde, google-chrome, chromium

All windows work fine but maximized G. Chrome window starts moving whenever I click under title bar without moving the cursor, but I don't want to move the windows, just to focus. 
Under the title bar is next to the tabs, on the blue part.
This is annoying. It goes from maximized to moving windows function, with the cross instead of the pointer, only with single steady click. Using KDE 4.8.4, kubuntu 12.04.
Something like this http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37013.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same issue with Firefox, pressing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key resolves it, but it's still annoying as I don't know what causes the resize at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

One workaroud is to use a chromiumtheme called "oxygenlike" and change som certain window rules specific to Chromium.

In that manner you avoid problems clicking inside the window right away, what happens if you don't use the standard KDE windowing.

The procedure is explained at: http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php?topic=78303.0

Even beter is to change the option in system settings, window behavoir, window behavior. Select the window actions tab. Whithin the "whitin inactive window" options choose for the left mouse button option "activate and bring to forground" option, but without "pass on click".

I use the dutch version of Kubuntu 10.04 LTS, so the menu/tab/button names can be slightly different in the english version than i translated it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! While your link may in theory answer the question, you may want to add the details contained here, in case the link changes.